# Why is my for loop terminating after only one iteration?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to write some basic code for a class that wants me to pick 3 random numbers and then ask the user for input and see if those random numbers match in different ways. Anyway i am specifically required to use a for loop to generate these 3 numbers, but it is only generating one. Please help.

**EDIT:** I removed the problematic line, however now it seems i concatenated wrong and my firstNumber, secondNumber, and all those kinds of variables are blank? I am not sure what is causing this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Lotteryv2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //Generate a random number

        String numberString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            double lotto = Math.random();
            int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);
            numberString += lotteryNumberDigit;


        }
        System.out.println(numberString);

        //extracting number string

        String firstNumber = numberString.substring(0,0);
        String secondNumber = numberString.substring(1,1);
        String thirdNumber = numberString.substring(2,2);
        String firstWin = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        String secondWin = secondNumber + thirdNumber;
        String allWin = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;
        // user guess
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter three numbers (e.g 123): ");
        String guess = input.next();
        if (guess.substring(0,2).equals(firstWin))
        {
            System.out.println("Winner! " + allWin);
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the first two numbers correctly!");
        }
        else if(guess.substring(1,3).equals(secondWin))
        {
            System.out.println("Winner! " + allWin);
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the last two numbers correctly!");
        }
        else if(guess.equals(allWin))
        {
            System.out.println("Winner! " + allWin);
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed all three numbers correctly!");
        }
        else
         {
            System.out.println("Winner! " + allWin);
            System.out.println("Sorry, you did not win");
        }
        //extracting three guess digits




    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the output as well ?

Comment: There is no point in having `numberString += lotteryNumberDigit;` if it is immediately followed by `numberString = Integer.toString(lotteryNumberDigit);`

Answer (score 3):

Your loop does go for three times. However, the visible result is the same as if it were doing only one iteration, because the second iteration writes over the results of the first one, and the third iteration overwrites the results of the second iteration before you do anything with them.

Here is the problematic line:

```
numberString = Integer.toString(lotteryNumberDigit);
```

Once you remove it, your code will print a three-digit numeric string (possibly with leading zeros).

Your code that extracts the individual digits also needs changing: since `endIndex` is *exclusive*, you need to add `1` to it:

```
String firstNumber = numberString.substring(0, 1);
String secondNumber = numberString.substring(1, 2);
String thirdNumber = numberString.substring(2, 3);
```

In addition, you need to check that the value the end-user entered is at least three digits long. Otherwise you are going to get exceptions when extracting digits from the `guess` variable.

Comment: Ok how would i fix that? I can not use array.

Comment: @DavidBrewer Your use of the string is OK for single-digit numbers.

Comment: Thank you, removing that line fixed it, however there seems to be a problem with the rest of the code. The if else statements always evaluate to the last else. Any idea why?

Comment: @DavidBrewer I would add a few `println`s to see the substrings you are producing. This should provide an explanation to you.

Comment: I did that and it seems that numberString is the last thing to have a value, and as soon as i try to assign String firstNumber = numberString.substring(0,0); everything looses its value. Am i not assigning it correctly?

Comment: @DavidBrewer `substring(0, 0)` is always empty, because the end index is *exclusive*. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value of the number to a single String variable, thereby overriding it in each iteration. You might change it to:

```
String[] numberStringArray = new String[3];
for(int i = 0; i < numberStringArray.length; i++)
        {
            double lotto = Math.random();
            int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);
            numberString += lotteryNumberDigit;
            numberStringArray[i] = Integer.toString(lotteryNumberDigit);
            System.out.println(numberStringArray[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, but the code you provided me does not. I am in a computer science course class and arrays are being introduced next chapter so i cant do that. are there any other ways to fix it?